# JavaScript slider code

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm making js-slider of div blocks. I have an arrows to the both sides. I want to scroll horizontally my slider when mouse is over. Before this I did everything using this code:

```
  jQuery('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
        jQuery('#slideInner').animate({
          'marginLeft' : SlideWidth * SlideNumber
        });
  });
```

But what to do, if I want slide everything until mouse is over `.control`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `setInterval(...)` to be delay-looping while element is hovered

```
var interval = null; // I use global var for this example - globals are discouraged in general
jQuery('.control')
    .hover(function(){
        interval = setInterval(function() { // start looping when mouse enters
            jQuery('#slideInner').animate({
               'marginLeft' : SlideWidth * SlideNumber
            });
        },
        1000); // this is how many milliseconds you want to wait between animations
     }, function(){
        clearInterval(interval); // stop looping when mouse is out
     });
```

Note: this is an oversimplification and requires further work (e.g. check for margin not to go out of bounds, etc), but it's intention is to show how `setInterval(...)` could be applied for your problem.

Comment: +1 reading this I felt like i'm in school. You are a born teacher.